# Why is this seemingly not very active user ranked so high when sorting meta users by participation?

Tags: support

Look at the participation-sorted tab of users (same order on responsive and mobile sites on my phone):

[image: John Omelian is above Alex]

[John Omielan](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/118359/john-omielan) only has 5 actions, with no posts or reputation gains other than the association bonus:

[image: They've commented 3 times, and earned a bronze badge and a silver badge. The silver badge, their most recent action, was on August 2, one month and 21 days ago.]

However, [Alex](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/100430/alex), a very prominent user, has hundreds more actions:

[image: They have 302 actions, the most recent being a comment on September 3 and a bronze badge on August 27. They have 31 posts.]

**Is this a bug, or is there some extremely convoluted logic here?**

---

Note to John: I’m not trying to single you out, this is just a weird behavior of the site.

Comment: No worries about singling me out.  It's helpful to have an example of any particular issue you're asking about, with me being a convenient one in this case. There's nothing negative or anything else you're stating about me, so it doesn't bother me that you used me as a specific example in this case.  As the answer by TheLethalCarrot below indicates, my regularly checking on, and often voting, on meta is likely an important factor in my relatively high activity "ranking".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Participation is calculated by](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149097/345161):

> Users most active on this site in the last 60 days (combined number of posts, votes, comments and edits).

John has the fourth most votes on meta for the quarter, see [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Voters&filter=quarter), 29 more than Alex so it is likely to do with that.